# Adding values to gdb (Linux)

Tags: gdb, nasm

I have a program to debug but it uses two variables (input). How do i add that to the following line?

```
gdb -tui hello
```

Comment: `gdb -tui --args hello arg1 arg2`

Comment: Thanks, tried looking it up, but i guess i used the wrong words to formulate the question...